# Read from pub/sub and write into Firestore (native) using Beam Dataflow streaming (python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am reading from pub/sub using Dataflow sliding windows, applying some transformations before creating entities and writing into Firestore native. I see that beam does not support native Firestore I/O library, hence I checked some custom [python code][https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/uploading-data-firestore-using-dataflow/] in order to write into Firestore. Here are the main important steps:

1- Create pub/sub sliding window:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    # Read data from Pub/Sub
    input_data = (
        p
        | "Read from Pub/Sub"
        >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription)
        | "Decode JSON" >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x))

    )
    windowed_data = (
        input_data
        | "Apply Windowing"
        >> beam.WindowInto(
            beam.window.SlidingWindows(
                size=60 * 60 * 5, period=60 * 15
            )  # sliding window of 5 hours, triggers every 15 min
        )
    )
```

2- create entities:

```
def create_content(element, window=DoFn.WindowParam):

logging.info(f" element is : {element}")
product_id = element[0]
window_start = window.start.to_utc_datetime()
window_end = window.end.to_utc_datetime()
# set expiry date of one hour
expiry_timestamp = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=5)


# create entity
entity = {
    "expiry_timestamp": expiry_timestamp,
    "product_id": product_id,
    "length_list": len(element[1]),
    "window_start": window_start,
    "window_end": window_end,
}
return entity
```

3- Write into Firestore class:

```
class FirestoreUpdateDoFn(beam.DoFn):
MAX_DOCUMENTS = 200

def __init__(self, project, collection):
    self._project = project
    self._collection = collection
    
def start_bundle(self):
    from google.cloud import firestore

    self._mutations = []
    self.db = firestore.Client(project=self._project)
    self.batch = self.db.batch()

def finish_bundle(self):
    if self._mutations:
        self._flush_batch()
        logging.info("committing batch of elements at finish_bundle")
    logging.info("closing db")
    self.db.close()

def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
    self._mutations.append(element)
    logging.info(f"read element is {element}")
    if len(self._mutations) > self.MAX_DOCUMENTS:
        self._flush_batch()

def _flush_batch(self):
    logging.info(f"length batch is {len(self._mutations)}")
    for mutation in self._mutations:
        logging.info(f"mutation is {mutation}")
        product_id = mutation["product_id"]
        key = hashlib.sha1(
            json.dumps(product_id, sort_keys=True).encode("utf-8")
        ).hexdigest()
        ref = self.db.collection(self._collection).document(key)
        self.batch.set(ref, mutation)
    logging.info("about to commit batch")
    r = self.batch.commit()
    logging.info("committing batch of elements")
    logging.debug(r)
    self._mutations = []
```

4- run it all together:

```
windowed_data | "Create entities" >> beam.Map(
        create_content
    ) | "Write to Firestore" >> beam.ParDo(
        FirestoreUpdateDoFn(project_id, collection_id)
    )
```

I used FirestoreUpdateDoFn bundles in order to batch insert into Firestore which i expected to improve performance by reducing back and forth between Dataflow and Datastore. However, I noticed that writing into Firestore still super slow. Aditionally, after around few minutes from job start the dataflow job stucks and data stops written to the Database. Furthemore, pub/sub backlog increases indefinitely which means that messages are not acknowledged (if i'm not mistaken).
I also noticed that bundles are super small which mostly resulted in small batches (mostly size is 1, see screenshot).

Currenltly, I am stuck since the job is not reliable (it become super slow and stops writing) and I am not sure if there is way to stream events into Firestore using beam python. any hints?

[image]

Comment: 1. to narrow down the bottleneck, try to remove the firestore part first.

2. Try https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.util.html#apache_beam.transforms.util.GroupIntoBatches to before the firestor part

3. you perhaps need to check https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns to build more robust custom IO

4. you perhaps need to add backoff retry since the db connections might be limited.

Answer (score 1):

Your overall idea goes the right way, however, it is incorrectly implemented within the `Beam` framework.

In particular, your `_mutations` does not the work the way you intend it to be. Instead of appending up to 200 messages, it only groups the messages within one PCollection/`element` within the process method. I am guessing, each PCollection contains only one item, hence you see a batch length of 1.

In order to collect messages from different elements, you need to use [Beam states](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers) (i.e., [BagStates](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#bagstate)). The documentation is pretty solid for this one, so allow me to just copy and slightly adjust the [example pseudocode](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#batching-rpcs) from the programming guide:

```
class BufferDoFn(DoFn):
  BUFFER = BagStateSpec('buffer', EventCoder())  # you need to use a fitting Coder for your case

  def process(self,
              buffer=DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER)):
    key, value = element
    
    buffer.add(value)  # equivalent to your _mutations.append(element)
    # instead of reading the whole list (as below) you can also introduce a second state (ReadModifyWriteStateSpec) for counting how many messages are in the bagstate -> could be more performant
    if len(list(buffer.read())) > self.MAX_DOCUMENTS:
       self._flush_batch()  # <- read buffer in there
```

Keep in mind, that a stateful `DoFn` requires a key-value pair to work. Each individual key produces a different state, which is independent of the rest. In your case you want to combine all incoming messages, thus you need to assign each incoming PCollection the same (dummy) key, e.g. something like this

```
_ = (
        p
        | "Add dummy key" >> beam.Map(lambda x: ('dummy_key', x)) # the key does not matter, but there has to be one if you want to use a state
        | beam.ParDo(BufferDoFn())
    )
```

By the way, you should move the initialization of the `Firestore` client into `setup()` and `teardown()` instead of start/finish bundle. Everything is processed in bundles within Beam, so they are called quite often, probably slowing you down as well.

Edit: the state is per key and window, i.e., each key and each window has its own state value. So for your use case, skip the windowing!